# How am I supposed to carry enough stuff to adventure?

Tags: equipment, encumbrance, pathfinder-2e-playtest

Encumbrance in Pathfinder 2 seems to be pretty limiting, and I always seem to run out of Container space long before I run out of Encumbrance space.

Backpacks can carry 4 Bulk worth of items, and Belt Pouches can carry 4 Light items each. Sheaths will hold your weapons just fine, but you're still not really left with much space to work with. If I max all of those out (assuming I can carry at most 4 Belt Pouches) I'm carrying about 6 or 7 Bulk worth of stuff. If I have 16 strength I still have at least 1 Bulk worth of space left to carry *stuff*. Wearing armor can fill that space, but how can I make use of that remaining Encumbrance without filling up my hands carrying sacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Sack tucked into your belt, which can hold 2 Bulk. (It's kinda like a large belt pouch.)

You can use a Satchel over your shoulder, which can hold 2 Bulk.

You can buy a slightly bigger backpack from someone.

Answer (score -5):

I thought the whole idea of going with the new Bulk system was to simplify encumbrance rules. Personally, I would just get your equipment up to your Bulk, and not worry about exactly how it's strapped to your body.